# Textblock Animation fadeout effect

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to animate textblock so i am doing like below and work perfect

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="Hello World">
  <TextBlock.Triggers>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
       <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txt"  
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  
             From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"  
             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
           />
         </Storyboard>                                          
       </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger>
   </TextBlock.Triggers>
 </TextBlock>
```

But What should i do if i want to do that textblock disappear after some time and after some clik or event fire on some controla again it should be working.? In sort i want to make it disappear after some time totally.

Comment: It's difficult to make out what you're trying to achieve. From what I understand, you want the textbox to fade out some time after an event (the Loaded event in your example) occurs. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can delay animation by adding BeginTime="0:0:5"  example

```
<DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="DelayedBeginTimeRectangle" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"  
            BeginTime="0:0:5" From="100" To="600" Duration="0:0:5" />
```

Also in your case remove  AutoReverse="True"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"